# Adding items to wxpython combobox...?

Tags: python, database, combobox, wxpython

I am new to python programming and to this forum as well. I am preparing a wxpython program (GUI) which has 2 comboboxes. First is for the Teams and the second for team members. All the data is stored into a access database and I am successful in fetching and adding the teams list to the teams combobox.

Now I want the team member combobox to load on the text change event of team combobox. for this I bind it using the EVT_TEXT method and called a self defined method to first take the team name from the team combobox and then run the query and load the relevant team members to the second combobox. to much extent I am successful but the team members are getting added to the team combobox itself.

Please have a look at the below code first:

```
import wx, pyodbc
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, Parent, Title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(None, title=Title, size=(400,400))
        #creating the panel in which all widgets will be stored/created.
        #self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, pos=(1,1),size=(382,100),style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
        #now creating the first Label inside the panel

        a = teamData()
        #rows = a.runQueryEmpList("Mama Badi")
        TmLst = a.runQueryTmList()
        abc=[]
        for r in TmLst:
            abc.append(r.Team_Name)

        #static box for the employee details
        self.myvbfrm = wx.StaticBox(self,-1,label="Employee Detail:-",pos=(1,1),size=(380,98))
        #items for the employee details
        LblName = wx.StaticText(self.myvbfrm,-1, 'Team Name:-',(8,20))
        LblName2 = wx.StaticText(self.myvbfrm,-1, 'Employee Name:-',(8,50))
        # team combobox
        TeamList = myComboBox(self.myvbfrm,(200,20),(100,50))
        TeamList.addItem(abc)
        # employee combobox
        #EmpList = wx.ComboBox(self.myvbfrm,-1,"",(200,50),(100,50))
        EmpList = myComboBox(self.myvbfrm,(200,50),(100,50))

        TeamList.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, TeamList.addTeamMember)

        #creating the panel in which all widgets will be stored/created.
        self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self, pos=(10,175),size=(365,150),style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
        #now creating the first Label inside the panel

        myFont = wx.Font(8,wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD,True)
        myLblFont = wx.Font(12,wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD,True)

        #Lbl.SetFont(myFont)
        #Lbl.SetForegroundColour((0,0,0))
        #Lbl.SetBackgroundColour((204,204,204))
        self.SetBackgroundColour((237,237,237))

        LblName.SetFont(myLblFont)
        LblName2.SetFont(myLblFont)

        # now under this __init__ method i will also initiate the method which
        # will create the MenuBar and the Menu Items.
        self.AddMenu()

    # now i will also have to create a method named as AddMenu so that
    # can be run (which will add the Menu Items.
    def AddMenu(self):
        myMenuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        myFileMenu = wx.Menu()
        myEditMenu = wx.Menu()
        exitBtn = myFileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Exit App')
        editBtn = myEditMenu.Append(wx.ID_MOVE_FRAME, 'Move App')
        myMenuBar.Append(myFileMenu, '&File')
        myMenuBar.Append(myEditMenu, '&Edit')
        self.SetMenuBar(myMenuBar)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

class teamData():

    def runQueryEmpList(self,Tname):
        self.Tname = Tname
        # set up some constants
        myDb = 'D:\\Python projects\\Python programs\\trial.accdb'
        DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
        PWD = 'pw'
        # connect to db
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s' % (myDb))
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # run a query and get the results 
        SQL = 'SELECT Emp_Name FROM Table1 WHERE Team = ?'
        return cur.execute(SQL, self.Tname).fetchall()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

    def runQueryTmList(self):
        # set up some constants
        myDb = 'D:\\Python projects\\Python programs\\trial.accdb'
        DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
        PWD = 'pw'
        # connect to db
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s' % (myDb))
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # run a query and get the results 
        SQL = 'SELECT Team_Name FROM Teams'
        return cur.execute(SQL).fetchall()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

class myComboBox(wx.ComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent, lstposition, lstsize):
        super(myComboBox, self).__init__(parent, -1, value="", pos=lstposition, size=lstsize)

    def addItem(self, Lst=[]):
        self.Lst = Lst
        for el in self.Lst:
            self.Append(el)

    def addTeamMember(self,extra):
        self.extra = extra
        a = teamData()
        rows = a.runQueryEmpList(self.GetValue())
        Emp_List=[]
        for r in rows:
            self.Append(r.Emp_Name)



class myFrm(wx.StaticBox):
    def __init__(self, parent, lblstring, position, BxSize):
        super(myFrm, self).__init__(parent,-1,label=lblstring,pos=position,size=BxSize)

    def borderColor(self):
        self



app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Clysdale Activity Tracker')
app.MainLoop()
```

I understand why they are getting added to the team combobox (because I am Append'ing the items to self). How should I refer to the other combobox in `addTeamMember()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would bind to a handler in your frame or panel and have the comboboxes defined as class variables:

```
self.TeamList = myComboBox(self.myvbfrm,(200,20),(100,50))
self.TeamList.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.onUpdate)
self.EmpList = myComboBox(self.myvbfrm,(200,50),(100,50))
```

Then you could just append items in the handler:

```
def onUpdate(self, event):
    team = self.TeamList.GetValue()
    if team == "Tigers":
        self.EmpList.append(some_list)
```

If you want to keep your way of doing things, then create the EmpList object first and pass it into the myComboBox class as another parameter when you create TeamList. Then you can append to it in the TeamList instance. Something like the following should work:

```
import wx, pyodbc
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, Parent, Title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(None, title=Title, size=(400,400))
        #creating the panel in which all widgets will be stored/created.
        #self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, pos=(1,1),size=(382,100),style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
        #now creating the first Label inside the panel

        a = teamData()
        #rows = a.runQueryEmpList("Mama Badi")
        TmLst = a.runQueryTmList()
        abc=[]
        for r in TmLst:
            abc.append(r.Team_Name)

        #static box for the employee details
        self.myvbfrm = wx.StaticBox(self,-1,label="Employee Detail:-",pos=(1,1),size=(380,98))
        #items for the employee details
        LblName = wx.StaticText(self.myvbfrm,-1, 'Team Name:-',(8,20))
        LblName2 = wx.StaticText(self.myvbfrm,-1, 'Employee Name:-',(8,50))
        # employee combobox
        #EmpList = wx.ComboBox(self.myvbfrm,-1,"",(200,50),(100,50))
        EmpList = EmpComboBox(self.myvbfrm,(200,50),(100,50))

        # team combobox
        TeamList = TeamComboBox(self.myvbfrm,(200,20),(100,50), EmpList)
        TeamList.addItem(abc)
        TeamList.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, TeamList.addTeamMember)

        #creating the panel in which all widgets will be stored/created.
        self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self, pos=(10,175),size=(365,150),style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
        #now creating the first Label inside the panel

        myFont = wx.Font(8,wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD,True)
        myLblFont = wx.Font(12,wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD,True)

        #Lbl.SetFont(myFont)
        #Lbl.SetForegroundColour((0,0,0))
        #Lbl.SetBackgroundColour((204,204,204))
        self.SetBackgroundColour((237,237,237))

        LblName.SetFont(myLblFont)
        LblName2.SetFont(myLblFont)

        # now under this __init__ method i will also initiate the method which
        # will create the MenuBar and the Menu Items.
        self.AddMenu()

    # now i will also have to create a method named as AddMenu so that
    # can be run (which will add the Menu Items.
    def AddMenu(self):
        myMenuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        myFileMenu = wx.Menu()
        myEditMenu = wx.Menu()
        exitBtn = myFileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Exit App')
        editBtn = myEditMenu.Append(wx.ID_MOVE_FRAME, 'Move App')
        myMenuBar.Append(myFileMenu, '&File')
        myMenuBar.Append(myEditMenu, '&Edit')
        self.SetMenuBar(myMenuBar)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

class myComboBox(wx.ComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent, lstposition, lstsize):
        super(myComboBox, self).__init__(parent, -1, value="", pos=lstposition, size=lstsize)

    def addItem(self, Lst=[]):
        self.Lst = Lst
        for el in self.Lst:
            self.Append(el)

    def addTeamMember(self,extra):
        raise NotImplementedError

########################################################################
class EmpComboBox(myComboBox):
    """"""
    pass

########################################################################
class TeamComboBox(myComboBox):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, lstposition, lstsize, empComboBox=None):
        """Constructor"""
        super(myComboBox, self).__init__(parent, -1, value="", pos=lstposition, size=lstsize)
        self.empComboBox = empComboBox


    def addTeamMember(self,extra):
        self.extra = extra
        a = teamData()
        rows = a.runQueryEmpList(self.GetValue()) 
        for r in rows:
            self.empComboBox.Append(r.Emp_Name)


class myFrm(wx.StaticBox):
    def __init__(self, parent, lblstring, position, BxSize):
        super(myFrm, self).__init__(parent,-1,label=lblstring,pos=position,size=BxSize)

    def borderColor(self):
        self



app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Clysdale Activity Tracker')
app.MainLoop()
```

Basically you'll want to subclass your ComboBox class and override the addTeamMember method. Since I couldn't run your code, I wasn't able to test the example above, but I believe it will work (although it might need a tweak here or there).

Comment: Thank you so much Mike for the help. Your solution worked for me. However being a new learner I also want to know how to pass the EmpList object into the myComboBox class as another parameter. If you can give me a little code example... Thanks again for your knowledge sharing... Have a very good day :).

Comment: I added an example, although I couldn't test it